# import information into existing csv file android

Tags: android, csv

My application does create every day a new CSV file. 
Now I want to write a new line with some information. This should happen when I press a button.
My problem is, that I don't know how I can open the existing file and continues where the last information was write. I did try a lot, but I didn't find a solution.

Create file

```
File myFile = new File("/sdcard/Protokolle" + date
                    + "/Protokoll.csv");
            myFile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

            myOutWriter.append("Date");
            myOutWriter.append(',');
            myOutWriter.append(date);
            myOutWriter.append('\n');
            myOutWriter.append('\n');

            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.close();
```

onClick

```
FileWriter fWriter;

            try {

                File sdCardFile = new File("/sdcard/Protokolle" + date + "/Protokoll.csv");
                Log.d("TAG", sdCardFile.getPath());

                fWriter = new FileWriter(sdCardFile, true);
                fWriter.write("\n");
                fWriter.write("Test");
                fWriter.write("Test");
                fWriter.write("\n");
                fWriter.write("test");

                fWriter.flush();
                fWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: A simple and maybe unprofessional way is to read the file, iterate trough all lines and after this procedure append a new line.

Answer (score 0):

change your code to

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(Protokoll,true);
```

this allows you to append to an existing file. See [Java API doc for FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html). If the file does not exist, the file is created otherwise the content will be appended.

Comment: I don't get an error but it doesn't add the informations.